# Snowflake/SQL - Nested json objects and arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, json, nested, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got stuck - I have a json file with a few nested json objects and arrays and I can't figure out how to query this data properly.

```
{
  "dim":[
    "ENT1",
    "ENT2",
    "ENT3",
    "ENT4"
  ],
  "col":[
    [
      "ST1",
      "ST2",
      "ST3"
    ]
  ],
  "row":[
    {
      "head":[
        "AC1"
      ],
      "data":[
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "head":[
        "AC2"
      ],
      "data":[
        "4",
        "5",
        "6"
      ]
    },
    {
      "head":[
        "AC3"
      ],
      "data":[
        "7",
        "8",
        "9"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are the expected resluts:

```
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC1, 1
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC2, 4
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC3, 7
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC1, 2
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC2, 5
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC3, 8
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC1, 3
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC2, 6
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC3, 9
```

Here are the results I'm receiving:

```
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC1, 1
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC1, 2
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC1, 3
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC2, 4
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC2, 5
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC2, 6
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC3, 7
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC3, 8
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST1, AC3, 9
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC1, 1
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC1, 2
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC1, 3
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC2, 4
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC2, 5
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC2, 6
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC3, 7
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC3, 8
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST2, AC3, 9
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC1, 1
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC1, 2
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC1, 3
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC2, 4
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC2, 5
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC2, 6
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC3, 7
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC3, 8
ENT1, ENT2, ENT3, ENT4, ST3, AC3, 9
```

And here is my query:

```
`SELECT t.$1:dim[0]::string AS pov1,
t.$1:dim[1]::string AS pov2,
t.$1:dim[2]::string AS pov3,
t.$1:dim[3]::string AS pov4,
s.value::string AS st,
a.value:head::string AS ac,
am.value::string AS at
FROM my_table t
, table(flatten( input => array_flatten(t.$1:col) ) s
, lateral flatten ( input => t.$1:row ) a
, table(flatten( input => a.value:data)) am;`
```

My SQL skills are not great so if anyone can enlighten me it would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you want, but it seems like from your output you're trying to get the row value at a particular column index.  If this is the case, snowflake provides a lot of meta information from flattened arrays, including the **index** of an element.

So you can just use the column array index to get the data for the corresponding row without even having to create another table alias since you already have row.

```
SELECT t.$1:dim[0]::string AS pov1,
  t.$1:dim[1]::string AS pov2,
  t.$1:dim[2]::string AS pov3,
  t.$1:dim[3]::string AS pov4,
  s.value::string AS st,
  a.value:head::string AS ac,
  a.value:data[s.index] AS at -- Get the data value corresponding to the column's index
FROM my_table t
  , table(flatten( input => array_flatten(t.$1:col) )) s
  , lateral flatten ( input => t.$1:row ) a
```

Comment: Yo Yo Ma! That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks Daniel, you saved my life! :)